# Using the selected items in Sqldatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I use the results of the select method in SqlDatasource like assign the returned id to a variable ?

Comment: i would not use SqlDataSource unless you are doing a quick&dirty tool or a throw-away-prototype.

Answer (score 1):

By default the SqlDataSource returns a System.Data.DataView object from its select method:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource source = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource("Connection String", "Select Query");
System.Data.DataView view = (System.Data.DataView)source.Select(System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
```

The System.Data.DataView object is a collection of System.Data.DataRowView so if you wanted to get the value of "pk" column for the first object you do this:

```
int itemIndex = 0;
String ColumnName = "pk";
int ID = view[itemIndex][ColumnName];
```